# How to embed camunda tasklist into a react application using iFrame

Tags: camunda

My requirement is I want to fully embed the Camunda tasklist into a react application using iFrame. Is that possible in Camunda 8? I am using Camunda 8 self-managed. I embedded Camunda 7 tasklist by disabling the x-frame option and content security policy but was not able to find how can I do the same in Camunda 8.

When I try to embed It shows localhost refuse to connect